# Sequelize | Return results if either hasMany association matches their where conditions

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, hapi.js

I have model **A**, **B**, and **C**.

**A** has a hasMany association to **B** & **C** ( and **B** & **C** have a belongsTo association back to **A** )

I want to return records of **A where B.b_column = 'b' OR C.c_column = 'c'**.

My current approach was to trying using the ***required: false*** in the where's but that just returns all the records of A and the associations IF they exist.  I also tried using ***separate: true*** on the associations, but it still seemed to be bringing back more records than I want.

```
var results = await A.all({
      include: [
        { 
          model: B, as: "Bs",
          where: { b_column: "b"},
          separate: true
        },
        { 
          model: C, as: "Cs",
          where: {c_column: "c"},
          separate: true
        },
      ]
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is query from root level

**Here you go :**

```
A.all({ // <------ I think this should be A not B as per your question
    include: [
        { 
          model: B, as: "Bs"
        },
        { 
          model: C, as: "Cs"
        },
    ],
    where : { 
                $or : [
                    { 'Bs.b_column' : "b" }, // <---- Might have to change table alias name
                    { 'Cs.c_column' : "c" }
                ]
            }
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I'm a nOOb and still wrapping my head around syntax and how it is converting to SQL. Only comment I have to make is that it needs to be '$Bs.b_column$' for it to pick it up.  Found that out quickly

Comment: @ndyr , yes you can use that one also.